# Mule:Assigning objectstore variable value to a flowVar

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have to maintain a count of messages (processing various different type of messages) that are processed in a flow. Using mule object store extension for this purpose

```
<objectstore:config name="storeDownLoad" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
<objectstore:store key="countA" value-ref="3" config-ref="storeDownLoad" />
```

How can i add one for each key  value and reassign it to object store and also how can i retrieve this value in a flowVar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-objectstore/blob/master/src/test/resources/mule-config.xml

It has examples of retrieving object store values and putting them in variables. See the "retrieveVariable" flow. Alternatively you can wrap the retrieve in an enricher.